# Analyzing Two Strings

Tags: java, string

Given two String variables, `s1` and `s2`, is it possible for `(s1 != s2)` to be true while `(s1.equals(s2))` is also true?

I would say no because if `String s1 = "Hello";`
and                       `String s2 = "hello";`
not equal due to "h" vs "H" but the second part can't be true then because when compared as objects they are not identical as well.  Would that make sense?

Comment: Two distinct String objects, with same content will have those conditions met.

Comment: What do you think about this one: `String a = new String("ABC"); String b = new String ("ABC");`? Both of these should hold your both conditions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Just make sure they're identical but not the same reference(i.e. don't intern or use the string pool via literals). Here's an example:

```
String s1="teststring";
String s2 = new String("teststring");
System.out.println(s1 != s2); //prints true, different references
System.out.println(s1.equals(s2)); //true as well, identical content.
```

Answer (score 2):

For two Strings, `s1` and `s2`,

```
(s1 != s2)     //Compares the memory location of where the pointers, 
               //s1 and s2, point to

(s1.equals(s2) //compares the contents of the strings
```

So, for `s1 = "Hello World"` and `s2 = "Hello World"`:

```
(s1 == s2) //returns false, these do not point to the same memory location
(s1 != s2) //returns true... because they don't point to the same memory location

(s1.equals(s2)) //returns true, the contents are identical
!(s1.equals(s2)) //returns false
```

In the case of `s1 = "Hello World"` and `s2 = "hello world"`,

```
(s1.equals(s2)) //This returns false because the characters at index 0 
                //and 6 are different
```

And finally, if you want a case-insensitive comparison, you can do this:

```
(s1.toLowerCase().equals(s2.toLowerCase()))  //this will make all the characters 
                                             //in each string lower case before
                                             //comparing them to each other (but
                                             //the values in s1 and s2 aren't 
                                             //actually changed)
```

Comment: That says what these comparisons do, not how to get the result the OP wants.

Comment: It's explaining the concept behind it, but take care you wrote pointers instead of references.

Comment: @hexafraction I think my answer now offers a more complete explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
String s1 = new String("Hello");
String s2 = new String("Hello");
```

`s1 == s2` returns `false`

`s1.equals(s2)` returns `true`

Thus, yes, it's possible since those strings aren't saved/checked within a common pool memory by default because not literal.